# How to present popover view and dismiss in appDelegate Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, uiviewcontroller

I'm not familiar with Objective-C and need help for present popover view controller in appDelegate when user tap the push notification bubble.

I can present popover for the vc I want but can not dismiss it. I think I didn't set the root? Please help. Thanks!

My storyboard flow:

```
[Navigation Controller][ViewControllerA] -> [ViewControllerB] -> [ViewControllerC]
```

My code can only show ViewControllerC and the dismiss button doesn't work (to dismiss to ViewControllerB).

I want to be able to tap the close button to dismiss ViewControllerC to ViewControllerB, and tap the close button on B to go to A.

```
//AppDelegate.m

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

    
    if ([(userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey])  isEqual: @"ViewControllerC"]) {
        
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        ViewControllerC *vc = (ViewControllerC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
        
    } else {
        //go to another vc
    }

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  completionHandler();
}


//ViewControllerA.m 
- (void) ViewControllerB_BackButtonPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


//ViewControllerB.m
- (void) ViewControllerC_BackButtonPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate ViewControllerB_BackButtonPressed];
}


//ViewControllerC.m
- (IBAction) backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate ViewControllerC_BackButtonPressed];
}
```

Comment: your looking on something like push/pop your viewControllers? So it's like stacking them on top of each other? like sheets of paper on a pile? and then remove them from top down until you get the lowest one? Is this what you try to achieve? If so do these viewControllers overlap completely? So if B is visible you cannot see A?

Comment: Hi, yes. I'm able to make them like stack on top of each other but having problem with dismissing them. I don't want to use navigation bar back button. I want to use the UIButton in the VC but it's not getting call.

Comment: When in A you create B. While doing that make A delegate of B. Then in B you call the "closeB" method. While you're in B creating C make B the delegate of C and so on. Make sure each VC has a view at the very bottom that doesn't propagate click through. Make sure a reference of B is stored in A.

Comment: There are also other ways of doing this depending on which OS you're in (ios or macOS)

Comment: It's for iOS development. The code I provide has the delegate links between the view controllers but the backButtibPressed (dismissViewController) func is not getting call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up skipping ViewControllerB to just present popover C on top of the A.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response 
withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
         
    ViewControllerA *viewControllerA = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];
    
    //check top view controller
    UIViewController *topViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
        while (true) {
            if (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
                topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
            } else if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)topViewController;
                topViewController = nav.topViewController;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (topViewController != viewController) {
            [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    
        if ([(userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey])  isEqual: @"ViewControllerC"]) {
                
            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *viewControllerC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerC"];
            viewControllerC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

            viewControllerC.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewControllerC animated:YES completion:NULL];
                
        } else {
            //go to another vc
        }
    completionHandler();
}
```